# Setting overflow:hidden to body/html hides scrollbars but does not disable scrolling in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, scroll

I can disable the scrolling in Chrome/Safari but putting overflow hidden on the body tag, but on Firefox this only hides the scrollbars and I can still scroll with the arrow keys. Why is this?

Also I'm animating using jQuery to slide down to a particular area on my page. With FF i have to animate the html tag but with Chrome/Safari it is just the body I need to animate. Haven't tested in IE yet but I'm expecting that to be an abomination :D.

So how come I can disable scrolling of the body on Chrome but not FF?

Note: Oh and i have tried setting overflow hidden on the html tag for FF but this just makes it jump to top (overflow hidden on body works fine for both browsers).

Comment: Why not just use a container DIV instead of the body/html?

Comment: Are you suggesting a container div just within the body? Do you reckon FF will react properly to this?

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/pqAJK/10/

Comment: kind of, but not really. the body/html is still scrollable with the arrow keys in FF when i have turned scrolling off using overflow:hidden. in chrome it works as expected. +1 for the effort, but it's not really what i'm going for.

Answer (score 4):

You may set the position of body to "fixed"

Answer (score 2):

I was able to achieve this in Firefox by binding a jQuery listener for `keydown` event on the `html` element and returning `false`.

```
// Disable Scrolling by keys
$("html").keydown(function(event) {
    switch(event.keyCode) {
        case 32://space
        case 33://pgup
        case 34://pgdn
        case 35://end
        case 36://home
        case 37://left
        case 38://up
        case 39://right
        case 40://down
            return false;
    }
});
```

I tried jQuery's `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopImmediatePropogation()` to no effect.

Answer (score 0):

If the only way it scrolls is with the arrow keys, you could probably just return false on keypress to prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

if using keydown function then textarea scroll using keys is not working... so i have done with below code. fixed my problem with firefox scroll issue.

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
  window.scrollTo(0,0);
});
```