# How to disable the main viewport browser scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way we could disable the browser scrollbar itself?
I'm not sure if this is a stupid question, but I really hope there are any alternative ideas you can suggest.

I am creating a Site following a Parallax effect with timeout. I want users to disable scrolling the browser so that it wont make the presentation screen get behind/advance, making its flow distorted.

I have already found a way to disable scrolling using mouse wheel and key strokes (thanks and Credits to this --> [How to disable scrolling temporarily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily)) but users can change the view by clicking on the browser scrollbar itself

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting overflow:hidden to body/html hides scrollbars but does not disable scrolling in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164861/setting-overflowhidden-to-body-html-hides-scrollbars-but-does-not-disable-scrol)

Comment: are you checking in IE7 ??

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').css("overflow", "hidden");
```

Should do the trick. Or add it via your stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

This might just work:

```
body{
    overflow: hidden;
    scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
    -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar { /* Chrome and Safari */
    display: none;
}
```

I use this all of the time and I haven't had any problems with that so far.